# Convexity of $(X, y) \mapsto y^T X^{-1} y$

Tags: convexity, convex-analysis

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $X \in \mathcal{S}^n_{++}(\mathbb{R})$. Why would function $ f : (X, y) \mapsto y^T X^{-1} y$ be convex?

---

I tried with $(X, x) + t.(Y, y)$ with no result. Also, I thought about using the eigenvalues of $X$, without result. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1070011/339790) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4088497/339790).

Answer (score 3):

This is shown in example 3.4 "Matrix Fractional Function" of [Convex Optimization – Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). The epigraph is transformed via Schur Complement (to handle the matrix inverse) into a convex LMI.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete proof.

1. One proves easily that if $S\in{\mathcal S}^n_{++}$ and if $zz^T\prec S$ (in the order between symmetric matrices), then
   $$\frac12 y^TX^{-1}y\ge z\cdot y-\frac12 {\rm Tr}(SX).$$
   **Hint**: start with the obvious inequality
   $$\frac12\left( y^TX^{-1}y+z^TXz\right)\ge z\cdot y.$$
2. On the other hand, the equality is achieved by taking $z=X^{-1}y$ and $S=X^{-1}yy^TX^{-1}$.
3. Hence we have
   $$\frac12 y^TX^{-1}y=\sup\left\{ z\cdot y-\frac12 {\rm Tr}(SX)\right\},$$
   where the supremum is taken among those $(z,S)$ such that $zz^T\prec S$.

Now the right-hand side, being the supremum of linear forms of $(y,X)$, is a convex function.